# Firebase understanding snapshot.child()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

consider this data structure referenced on the Firebase quick start guide ([here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/child.html))

```
{"name": {"first": "Fred","last": "Flintstone"}
```

The docs say that one can access the datasnapshot location of each child object of "name" returned from a query using:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/samplechat/users/fred");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
     var nameSnapshot = snapshot.child("name");
     var name = nameSnapshot.val();

     name === { first: "Fred", last: "Flintstone"}

     var firstNameSnapshot = snapshot.child("name/first");
     var firstName = firstNameSnapshot.val();
     firstName === "Fred"

     var lastNameSnapshot = snapshot.child("name").child("last");
     var lastName = lastNameSnapshot.val();
     lastName === "Flintstone"

     var ageSnapshot = snapshot.child("age");
     var age = ageSnapshot.val();
     age === null (because there is no "age" child in the data snapshot)
});
```

But what's a little weird about this is when the following lines are processed.

```
var nameSnapshot = snapshot.child("name");
var name = nameSnapshot.val();
```

**name.first**, and **name.last** are also retrieved. So why would one use this snapshot method "child()"? Or rather when would it be beneficial to use this method, since when you pull the parent object, Firebase pulls all children, or is there a way to retrieve a parent node/object without pulling some of it's children? Then this method to me would make sense.

Any information would be gratefully appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is there a way to retrieve a parent node/object without pulling some of it's children?

The Firebase JavaScript API always retrieves the complete node. So: no, there isn't a way in the JavaScript API to get a shallow result/

> why would one use this snapshot method `child()`?

If we compare `snapshot.child("property")` with `snapshot.val().property`. The `DataSnapshot.child()` method returns a `DataSnapshot`, from which you can get a `ref` again. The `val()` method deserializes the snapshot's value into JSON. So you'll have to construct your own ref if you'd need one. But the value of each depends highly on your use-case, so "why" is not something I can answer for you.

Comment: I was looking at the method .child() purely from the viewpoint of accessing a node's value, when in fact, as you have pointed out, one might need to retrieve a reference to a child node. Makes sense. In my case, I had an object 'requests' that had a 'comments' object as a child. The comments object contained several child nodes within them, so I was trying to see if I could retrieve the requests object, without retrieving the child comments object, because I didn't want to pull down every comment when someone queries a request.

Answer (score 1):

The snapshot is a exact picture of everything in the node at the time of the call. What it contains however, will vary depending on how you get the snapshot.

The example provided in the guide is slightly one-dimensional. In general you would not have a node called name with just one person listed.

A better example would be a node called users with data as such

```
users
  user_id_0
   firstName:
   lastName:
   age:
  user_id_1
   firstName:
   lastName:
   age:
```

When used with the Value parameter, the snapshot of the users node contains all of the node's children and all of the data within each child (in this case, all of the users and their data), and the block that handles it is called once. We use this to read, for example, all of the users in the users node and then iterate over the users for some specific data. We also use it to do multi-parameter queries, which are not supported directly by firebase. So for example, we want to get all users named Elmo, age 20.

The Add parameter reads each child, one at a time, calling the block once for child, which would be each user in this case.  Typically we use this to keep UI tableView's updated (ObjC) so when a new child data is added to Firebase, all of the apps who are observing will be notified, so we can then update our UI table.

You cannot retrieve a parent object without also retrieving the children. However, you can directly access a child if you know the parent object if you are looking for a specific piece of data.  So you could retrieve users/user_id_0/age

Comment: So say for instance, each child within users contains a child object called "comments", and this object could contain upwards of 200 comments (just purely hypothetical). If you wanted to pull a user, and the object's first 10 comments, from what you have explained this is not possible, so how then does one solve this problem? It's not efficient to pull down every comment, as that could be costly, and I might want to paginate/lazy-load comments on the fly. Is there a pattern to approaching this scenario?

Comment: Great question! It all comes down to how the data is structured. Firebase queries go 1 level deep, so in my example above, I could query for a single property like firstName = "Elmo" or age = "20". We could even query for ages starting at 20 and ending at 30. With the right data structure, you can query for the first 10 comments, last 10, today's comments etc. To your question: perhaps a Comments node called... Comments. Then each child is a comment_id and it's children are comment, user_id and comment_date_time. Then it could be queried for comment_date_time after 12am this morning.

Comment: I see. That makes a lot of sense. If I understand what you are saying, rather than have comments nested as a child object within each user, maybe have a top level comments node, where each comment child contains a copy of the commenter's user key. That, in a way and very simply would work, and I'm wondering why that never crossed my mind lol. Really appreciate the insight and explanation. I really love Firebase, it's just getting to re-adjust to the way it does things. Thank you so much.