# Firebase documentation standards?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I saw this snippet on a Firebase documentation page explaining a method. Is there any documentation on how to read this documentation?

```
onSnapshot ( options :  SnapshotListenOptions ,  observer :  { complete ?: ( ) => void ; error ?: ( error :  Error ) => void ; next ?: ( snapshot :  QuerySnapshot < T > ) => void } ) : ( ) => void
```

As I understand it, Javascript does not have typed arguments to functions, though I am very much a Javascript novice trying to build my first modern web app. I have no idea how to even read this documentation. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Your question is regarding understanding Firebase and its integration as an API? you can read from this post and see if it provides the right answer for you [Firebase Understanding snapshop.child()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31144859/firebase-understanding-snapshot-child)

Comment: My question is regarding understanding how to read the API documentation. I have not written Javascript since the late '90s so I guess the language changed a bit since then.

Comment: Generally programming books (back in the day when we had those) have a notation section explaining how to read the documentation. I can't find that for this documentation.

Comment: What you're seeing here is TypeScript, which is a superset of JavaScript that adds a declarative type system.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you! I found a spec for TypeScript which seems to be exactly the documentation I was looking for:https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md

Can you resubmit your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing here is TypeScript, which is a superset of JavaScript that adds a declarative type system.

These days a lot of new APIs are defined as TypeScript (typically in files ending with `.ts`), and existing APIs are recast with TypeScript types too (by creating a separate `.d.ts` file for them). You can still use them as good-old JavaScript as you want, but you can also use the new type-system and get the benefits of type checks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case:

1. `onSnapShot` is a function, since we open with `onSnapShot (` rather than `onSnapShot {` which would be for an object;
2. `onSnapShot` has arguments `options, observer`
3. `complete ?: ( ) => void ;` means that the object `observer` optionally has a property called `complete` that is a function (`()=>` is known as arrow functions and are equivalent to python's lambda expressions) and that complete should return nothing (or that its return result will be ignored anyway).
4. `onSnapshot` returns void.

re: the types: you're right in that javascript doesn't explicitly enforce typed arguments, but it isn't unreasonable for `onSnapShot` to expect something that contains all the (required) properties as documented in `SnapshotListenOptions`. So next step would be to dive down `SnapshotListenOptions` and see what is required.

If you really like a typed language, there's always typescript.

Comment: Thank you for an explanation. Is there a generic documentation defining this format, in particular what each character in the specification means? In languages such as C++ or Java the function signature is parsable by a compiler, is there a "compiler" for such function signatures?

Comment: maybe this? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html the docs seem fairly consistent w/ typescript formatting...

Comment: i see you've found a better reference in the comments of your question above ^